# Why is my usb flashdrive automatically mounted, without fstab?

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, permissions

I plugged in a usb storage device for the very first time, and it automatically mounted the FAT32 partition called "HMN"? At first i was pleasantly surprised, but it's mounted as root.

*Q: How can i find out what's mounting it, and how can i make the 'pi' user able to access it?*

I didn't start 'startx' (where it sees devices automatically).
mtab refers to HMN as:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/HMN vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

fstab is:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

I've got a RPI2 
Software version:

```
Linux raspberrypi2 3.18.5-v7+ #225 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 30 18:53:55 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Check if the package "usbmount" is installed. If so, see its manpage, have a look at '/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf' or use google.

Comment: It is most probably `udisks` that automounts your USB drive. Have a look at its manpage.

Comment: Hi. I typed "which udisk" and "which usbmount" but got no results. I also checked the list returned from apt-get, but those were not in there.  I did find udisks :)  using " dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep udisk
" Thanks

Comment: Do you know what is responsible for using 'udisks' for mounting?